# Why can sibling classes be referred to with dots from each other?

Tags: java, inner-classes

I just found a curious case.

```java
class SomeClass {

    abstract static class AbstractNested // for a templating purpose
            extends SomeClass {

    }

    static class Sibling1
            extends AbstractNested {

    }

    static class Sibling2
            extends AbstractNested {

    }

    void a() {
        new Sibling1.Sibling2(); // @@?
    }
}
```

Why on earth does `new Sibling1.Sibling2();` work? How can I make it doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Sibling1` and `Sibling2` aren't just siblings; they both **extend** the outer class (indirectly, via `AbstractNested`), and so they inherit the nested classes as members, just as they would  inherit methods or fields.

Simplified example:

```
class Outer {
    
    static class Inner extends Outer {}

    void a() {
        new Inner.Inner.Inner.Inner.Inner.Inner.Inner();
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As Boann's answer,the reason is that both `Sibling1` and `Sibling2` are extends from `AbstractNested`,and `AbstractNested` are extends from `SomeClass`, so they are all subclass of `SomeClass`,which means `new Sibling1.Sibling2()` is similar to `new SomeClass.Sibling2()`

If you remove `extends` from `Someclass` or `Sibling1` it will not compile

Case 1 (remove `extends` for `Sibling1`):

```
class SomeClass {

    abstract static class AbstractNested
            extends SomeClass {

    }

    static class Sibling1 {

    }

    static class Sibling2
            extends AbstractNested {

    }

    void a() {
        new Sibling1.Sibling2(); // will not compile
    }
}
```

Case 2 (remove `extends` for `SomeClass`):

```
class SomeClass {

    abstract static class AbstractNested {

    }

    static class Sibling1
            extends AbstractNested {

    }

    static class Sibling2
            extends AbstractNested {

    }

    void a() {
        new Sibling1.Sibling2(); // will not compile
    }
}
```